# Pusher error: auth_key should be a valid app key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, pusher

guys I did try work with edit and when I click on submit I have this error, but the changes was done and I am guessing why I have this issue

```
Pusher error: auth_key should be a valid app key .
```

This is my broadcasting.php

```
'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            'encrypted' => false,
            'useTLS' => false,
            'scheme' => 'http',
            // 'host' => env('PUSHER_HOST'),
            // 'port' => env('PUSHER_PORT', 6379),
            'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'http'),
            'curl_options' => [
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
            ]
          
        ],
    ],
```

And this .env file

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=995591
PUSHER_APP_KEY=644a4ac1988060882370
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=739696537f4fb23b8fcd
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=ap1
PUSHER_PORT=6379
PUSHER_SCHEME=http
PUSHER_HOST_PROXY=${HOST}
PUSHER_PATH_PROXY='/websockets'
PUSHER_PORT_PROXY=443
PUSHER_HOST=127.0.0.1
MIX_PUSHER_HOST=${HOST}
```

Comment: You really should not be sharing your secret with us. You should generate new credentials in the Pusher dashboard.

Comment: Do you mean create new Pusher_APP_KEY?

Comment: Because I did and have the same error as previously

Comment: I'm saying you should regenerate `PUSHER_APP_SECRET`, because you should **never** share that value with anyone outside your organization. Definitely not the entire internet.

Comment: After that, can you explain a bit about your setup? Why are you pointing `PUSHER_HOST` at `127.0.0.1`, for example? Your `.env` values indicate an unusual setup.

Comment: Ok, thank you I did copy this app_secret from another post in github. Where I need to generate it?

Comment: Did you copy the rest of this? You can't just copy someone else's key/secret and hope it works.

Comment: I did just some changes to form and did click submit.

Comment: I didn`t know about it, I thought it would be good and works well